# Как хранить разнородные параметры в БД?

Tags: mysql

У меня есть 3 типа устройств и у них наборы параметров в каждый момент времени, параметры разные, если что и разных типов(int, float).

Эти параметры логируются каждую минуту в БД.

Самый очевидный способ записи их в БД - сделать 3 разных таблицы с разным набором полей.

Но если вдруг в определенный момент я добавлю в одну из этих таблиц новое поле, то у меня появится куча пустых полей, это же не правильно?

А как бы вы поступили?

Comment: Предлагаемый вариант проще с т.з. получения данных (все в табличке, простой select). Можно хранить в узкой таблице пары значений (id события, тип значения, значение), но тут и оверхед побольше, и заселектить уже не так просто и удобно.

Comment: Выбор варианта зависит и от того, что с этими данными делать дальше - хранить 10 лет, выбирать для анализа и пр. Или устройств одного типа 1, а другого 10. А может, понадобится еще 1 тип устройств.

Comment: @Kromster да, первый вариант проще и быстрее с точки зрения исполнения кода(наверное)

Comment: @ValNik да, храниться это будет долго, устройств одного типа может быть несколько сотен

Comment: @ValNik и кода получается необходимо писать в N-раз больше, где N-количество типов устройств

Comment: Всё зависит от того, как Вы намерены ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ эти данные. Если только получать обратно - это одно. Если обрабатывать на стороне SQL (суммировать, искать среднее и пр.) - это другое. Если искать/сортировать и пр. - совсем третье.

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что вы пытаетесь навелосипедить мониторинг. Может, лучше взять Prometheus + Grafana?

Comment: Небольшие int'ы (примерно до 2^53) можно безопасно хранить в 64-битном float, а значит из текущего описания получается, что всё можно хранить в одном типе. А хранение кучи меняющихся во времени float'ов - это именно то, на что заточен Prometheus

Comment: @andreymal по сути да, есть задача организовать небольшой порталчик для детей собирающих умные теплицы для нашего конструктора таких теплиц, с передачей показаний 4 датчиков через модуль nodeMCU

Comment: @andreymal про Prometheus + Grafana не слышал до этого, обязательно изучу

Comment: (хотя есть нюанс - Prometheus не оптимизирован под реально долгое хранение данных. Несколько месяцев ещё ок, но если вдруг интересуют годы, то народ обычно городит какой-нибудь VictoriaMetrics сбоку в качестве долговременного хранилища)

Comment: @andreymal как я понял принцип работы Prometheus заключается в том, что он оправляет запросы к устройствам, но это не наш случай, тк устройства сами отправляют данные на сервер, а переделывать проблематично

Comment: Есть и такой нюанс, но можно написать какой-нибудь прокси, на который устройства будут скидывать метрики, а Prometheus будет уже считывать метрики с прокси (впрочем, такое количество нюансов поднимает вопрос, а надо ли оно вам вообще, так что не настаиваю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем большой респект за ваше мнение!

В итоге выбрал прагматичный подход, который посоветовал @Kromster в плане необходимости корректировать код, при добавлении новых типов устройств, тк каждый новый тип - новая таблица и соответственно дописывание новых методов для API.

С данными кроме вывода в табличку и построения графиков в обозримом будущем делать не планирую.